# Passing $variable from one php to another

Tags: php, variables

How could I send `$quantity` from cart.php and place it into index.php?

I've tried this:

**At index.php:**

```html
<?
session_start();
$quantity = $_SESSION['sessionVar'];
?>

<span><?php echo $quantity ;?></span>
```

**At cart.php:**

```php
<?php 
session_start();
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$_SESSION['sessionVar'] = $quantity;
?>
```

Would you suggest any solution here? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any problems with the current solution? You can either keep the values as a part of _SESSION or pass them via _GET. The latter is very inconvenient when you need to pass more than 1 value.

Comment: what problem you are facing? your code should work, session keeps its value until the browser is closed, you can get the value from any page. what is the value of     $_POST['quantity']  ? you can check if it has value with something like this  if(isset($_SESSION['someVar'])){}

Comment: i want to place cart products counter into index.php, but that code doesn't work, im sitting all day breaking my head but nothing comes to my mind..